# NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType'>'

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am using the rpy2 package to install another R package via python. My code is:

```
**import os
os.environ["R_LIBS_USER"] = r"C:\Program Files\RStudio\R\R-4.2.1"
import rpy2
print(rpy2.__version__)
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list**

**# R package names
packnames = ('fpmoutliers')
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))**
```

But I am getting an error :

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\conversion.py in _rpy2py(obj)
250     non-rpy2) objects.
251     """
--> 252     raise NotImplementedError(
253         "Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '%s'" %
254         str(type(obj))

NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType'>'

My R version is 4.2.1. and the rpy2 version installed is 3.5.2. Can anyone please help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Your code cannot even install this package as it is unlisted on the main cran repo. The package is outdated and causing errors in windows build. If you edit your code in OP so it could actually reach the said error, I can probably make a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Kesh. I just found out it has been removed. I collected the archived R files and trying the source the source codes directly in R but still facing error. Thinking of finding an alternate package having the same functionality

Comment: Ok. If you encounter the same issue, you need to create a custom converter to handle R's NULL data type (you can also try pandas2ri converter but not sure if it supports it either)

Comment: I used from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate() and a separate package isotree but still of no luck. Getting another error NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface_lib.sexp.NULLType'>'

Comment: Could you update (edit) the post to reflect the exact python script you are running?